# Is there an analytic form to find the invers of a matrix using jordan form?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition, jordan-normal-form

I know that any cyclic matrix can be inversed by diagonalaizing it $A = PDP^{-1}$ where the columns of $P$ are Fourier basis vectors and the diagonal of the (diagonal matrix) $D$ contains the eigenvalues of $A$ which are the discrete Fourier transrom on the elements of the generating vector of $A$. 
In this case we have a nice analytic formula for the inverse of $A$:

$$A^{-1} = PD^{-1}P^{-1}$$

**My question is:**

Given an invertible matrix, is there an analytic formula for it's inverse using it's Jordan form?
I am looking for something like the above equation which might be applied on not-necessarily cyclic matrices.

*Edit:* Also, Is there a canonical form for $J^{-1}$?

Thank you!

Comment: Invert every Jordan block.

Comment: FWIW: look up the formula for evaluating a matrix function at a Jordan block; this easily applies to your problem of finding an expression for $\mathbf J^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$A=C^{-1}JC \Rightarrow A^{-1}=C^{-1}J^{-1}C$$

Comment: Thanks! Is there a canonical form for $J^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes. You are very welcome.